# TCL using namespace in apply

Tags: namespaces, tcl

i have the below code

```
set result {}
apply {x {expr {$x*100}} ns2} {1,2,4}
```

In the above code what is the importance of namespace, how can i use namespace variable or store result to namespace

Answer (score 1):

Let's get a namespace and a namespace variable:

```
% namespace eval example {variable result 0}
```

Use the `variable` command to declare the name `result` to be a namespace variable within the lambda:

```
% apply {x {variable result ; set result [expr {$x * 100}]}} 3
% set ::example::result
# => 0
% set ::result
# => 300
```

The lambda used the global namespace since we didn't specify any namespace.

```
% apply {x {variable result ; set result [expr {$x * 100}]} ::example} 3
% set ::example::result
# => 300
```

And there it is.

Documentation:
[* (operator)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm),
[apply](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/apply.htm),
[expr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm),
[namespace](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/namespace.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm),
[variable](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/variable.htm)

Comment: peter i need urgent help for tcl code, can you help me. I need to chat, is there any way i can talk to you.

Comment: peter can you please message me @ace.kartik gmail.

Comment: @KartikV: sorry, I only answer questions here on Stackoverflow.